# Sublime to change Tcl syntax highlighting

Tags: sublimetext2, syntax-highlighting

In notepad++, the tcl command arguments get highlighted. Like this:
puts [my_tcl_command `-arg1` foo `-arg2` bar]
How can I change the syntax highlighting definition in Sublime Text 2. I guess it's somewhere in this file "`Sublime Text 2\Packages\TCL\Tcl.tmLanguage`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax highlighting in Sublime Text is controlled by two files - the `.tmLanguage` file, which you mentioned, and your theme's `.tmTheme` file. *Scopes* are assigned to your code by interpreting regular expressions contained in the `.tmLanguage` file. For example, `puts` is assigned the scopes `source.tcl keyword.other.tcl` You can determine this by putting your cursor in a certain spot, then hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> - the scope(s) will appear in the bottom bar. Alternatively, I highly recommend using the [`ScopeHunter`](https://github.com/facelessuser/ScopeHunter) plugin.

So, now that we have the scope, it's up to the `tmTheme` file to assign the syntax highlighting. Unless you've installed a plugin theme, these files live in the `Packages/Color Schemes - Default` directory. It's in XML format, and you can search for the scope that's assigned to your `-arg1` and `-arg2` arguments and change the colors - they're in hex RGB web format.

***EDIT***

I just re-read your question, and realized that you want to assign a *new* scope to highlight the arguments. For that, you'll need to edit the `.tmLanguage` file and add a new regex to highlight them, assign a scope, then either alter your `.tmTheme` to add the new scope, or just assign one that's already highlighted. I don't know that much about how Notepad++ assigns its syntax highlighting rules, so you may be able to find one already written. Taking a look at other `.tmLanguage` files can be very instructive, as well. I recommend the Python one, even though it's not terribly well organized, because there are a large number of scopes, and it's fairly easy to see what's being done.